# Numeric value error for small select query in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select to_varchar(nvl(cdi_source,'')) as  cd 
from customer_address 
WHERE best_address_ind = 1;
```

getting error like

`Numeric value 'posp' is not recognized.`

`cdi_source` field has data like this

```
12    KSRELP
 2    NMCAPT
 3    2018-11-12 00:00:00
 4    2019-03-15 0
```

Comment: Can you please share the types of each of the columns of the table? This can be done by DESC TABLE customer_address;

Comment: there is a bug (that I have reported and they are not going to fix) related if you have a where clause the will correctly filter a second columns results to be of only one type and `to_number` or the likes, that the to_number will fail of the rows that don't have the type (which also fail the filter). They break ANSI order of operations, to get speed. So just a FYI that if you have variant types you should use the TRY_TO_x to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the previous answer.

Try to run your query using TRY_TO_NUMBER like this:

```
select to_varchar(nvl(cdi_source,'')) as cd 
from customer_address 
WHERE try_to_number(best_address_ind) = 1;
```

Comment: Understood, When comparing data we should match the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for this error is if `best_address_ind` is a varchar etc. column and one row contains the value `posp`.